# Height of Browser Window and Divs

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to build a website with a banner of a fixed height (100px) at the top, and I want the rest of the content to fill the rest of the page. I have it so that I have the banner is in a div, and the rest of the page in another div, and I want the rest of the page to be the height less 100px (100% - 100px). Obviously you cannot mix % and px when it comes to height. However, is it possible to define a variable to be the widow height (100%) minus the banner height (100px) and then use this to define the height of my remaining div.

I am new to css, html and hardly know any other languages, so please try to keep answers simple, as I am a simple person!

Comment: What does it mean when you say you need to define the height to be 100%-100px? Is one of those a minimum, and the other a max?

Comment: I believe this would be the same as this other [question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434602/css-setting-width-height-as-percentage-minus-pixels

Comment: Thank you for all of your responses. Ozzyberto's link to another thread led me to having each of the side menu and content div as `position:fixed` with the following settings `top:100px; bottom:0;`. They were sitting inside my containing div which had `height:100%` and my body also had `height:100%`.

Answer (score 2):

Height is dynamic so that as you add content to your "content section", so will the size of the contianer thats holding it.

The short answer is, dont set a height for your "content section".

Comment: Unfortunately not setting a height doesn't work. However, I have found a solution (see the comment after my initial question).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="height: 100px">
   Your banner
</div>
<div>
  Body
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use 100% as the height of your content div - it will stretch to take up the space from your banner to the bottom of the screen.

An important part is to set the height of html and body to 100%:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Foo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="banner"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#banner {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/yHFjh/

Comment: Your content is 100% not 100% - 100px

Answer (score 0):

Create a html and body of `height` 100%. Position the banner absolute. Add a content div below your banner and set it's `min-height` to 100%. This content will be behind the banner, but will be at least 100%. Add a div in the content with a `padding-top` of the height of the banner to prevent content to end up underneath the banner.

HTML:

```
<div id="banner"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text..
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#banner { position: absolute; height: 100px; width: 100%; background: green; }
#content { min-height: 100%; background: yellow; }
#main { padding-top: 100px; }​
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/pY6dc/

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.innerHeight / document.documentElement.clientHeight` property

```
<div id="banner">banner</div>
<div id="content">content</div>

<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1){
        document.getElementById("content").style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - document.getElementById("banner").offsetHeight + "px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("content").style.height = window.innerHeight - document.getElementById("banner").offsetHeight + "px";
    }
</script>
```